# Firebase initializeApp(config); fun

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I really cant find this information ANYWHERE. Actually I found one place that had every db call in one js script.

Can someone please clarify if I'm supposed to run this:

```
var config = {
apiKey: "AAAPPPIIIIKKKEEEYYYYY",
authDomain: "test-db.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://test-db.firebaseio.com",
storageBucket: "test-db.appspot.com"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

On every page of my website? Or even just putting it into a js file and calling that file? How do I pass the initialized app around from page to page? Im not using Angular or react or node.js. I just want to use it with straight java script? Is this not possible?

If I call:

```
<script>
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            console.log('User!!')
        } else {
            console.log('Not User!!')
        }
    });
</script>
```

On a page that doesnt call my firebase.js, which the first 5 lines initialize the app, then I get "Not User". I cannot believe that they would want me to initialize the app on every page..

Comment: Firebase provides [SDK Auto Configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls#sdk_auto-configuration) which you can just include directly in a script tag

Comment: Thats only if its hosted with firebase/Google

Answer (score 2):

So I have found the answer..

```
Here is how you would track the Auth state across all your pages:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sample FirebaseUI App</title>
<!-- *******************************************************************************************
   * TODO(DEVELOPER): Paste the initialization snippet from:
   * Firebase Console > Overview > Add Firebase to your web app. *
   ***************************************************************************************** -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  initApp = function() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        var displayName = user.displayName;
        var email = user.email;
        var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
        var photoURL = user.photoURL;
        var uid = user.uid;
        var phoneNumber = user.phoneNumber;
        var providerData = user.providerData;
        user.getIdToken().then(function(accessToken) {
          document.getElementById('sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed in';
          document.getElementById('sign-in').textContent = 'Sign out';
          document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = JSON.stringify({
            displayName: displayName,
            email: email,
            emailVerified: emailVerified,
            phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
            photoURL: photoURL,
            uid: uid,
            accessToken: accessToken,
            providerData: providerData
          }, null, '  ');
        });
      } else {
        // User is signed out.
        document.getElementById('sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed out';
        document.getElementById('sign-in').textContent = 'Sign in';
        document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = 'null';
      }
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    initApp()
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to My Awesome App</h1>
<div id="sign-in-status"></div>
<div id="sign-in"></div>
<div id="account-details"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here they finally say that "here is how you would track the Auth state across """"""ALL""""""" your pages. Took me awhile but I finally found an answer. Apparently they DO want you to initialize the app on every page. Hmmm

Answer (score 1):

For anyone landing here from a Google search trying to figure out what options/apikeys/authdomain etc data to put into the `firebase.initializeApp()`, you may have created the Firebase *project*, but not added the Firebase *app* to the project.

- Go to the console https://console.firebase.google.com/
- Click the *project*
- Click "Add App" (or look for an existing app)

All the info you need should be there, at the time of writing in the section "Firebase SDK snippet".

This doesn't exactly answer the OP's question though.

The original question is a general web-app-using-JavaScript question, not a Firebase question really. Naturally for the JavaScript code on every "page" to run it will need all the objects on that page to be full and correct. It's more of a webpack/general JavaScript thing.