# Is (firebase 9) initializeApp() necessary for email login?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Related:

[Firebase initializeApp(config); fun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659553/firebase-initializeappconfig-fun)

Does an app need to call `intializeApp()` for gmail login?

The docs mention that, "yes", a config object needs to be passed to `initializeApp()`, yet, functionally, login and db reads can be done outside the firebase sdk (user login).

Is there any workaround where the config is not used (I don't have access to it at)?

Comment: "Does an app need to call intializeApp() for gmail login?" - yes.  "Is there any workaround where the config is not used (I don't have access to it at)?" - no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `initializeApp` tells the SDK what Firebase project to connect to on the servers. So: yes, you need to call `initializeApp` before you can call the SDK method to sign in with email/password.